# Show all options in Django ManyToMany form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have two Django models, connected with a ManyToMany relationship via a 'through' model:

```
class Tag(Model):
     uuid = UUIDField(auto=True, version=4, primary_key=True)
     name = CharField(max_length=100)

class Agent(Model):
    uuid = UUIDField(auto=True, version=4, primary_key=True)
    tags = ManyToManyField(
        'Tag', blank=True, null=True, through='AgentTag')

class AgentTag(Model):
    agent = ForeignKey(Agent)
    tag = ForeignKey(Tag)
    experience = IntegerField()
```

I'd like to create a form showing all tags in the Tag model, alongside dropdowns for the agent to record his/her experience in each tag. If the user has previously updated their experience, the form should be initialized with this. Saving the form should update the AgentTag "through" table.

What type of form (or formsets?) do I need to achieve this? I'm not sure whether it should be a ModelForm for AgentTag or a bespoke Form. Much appreciate some help on how to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A FormSet seems unnecessary complex here, though it could be just me not being in the habit of using formsets.

I’d say in your view you could just:

1. Get a list of all existing `Tag`s.
2. Get an `AgentTag` for each of the `Tag`s, create if missing[0]. For ones that already exist you’ll have experience pre-filled in their forms.
3. Iterating over `AgentTag`s, initialize a `ModelForm` *with unique [`prefix`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms)* for each.

When the form is submitted, your view would iterate over available `AgentTag`s, construct a form for each based on the data POSTed, and save the resulting objects.

You could also consider updating experiences with async HTTP (AJAX) requests from your client-side whenever user modifies an experience dropdown, but that’s going to be somewhat more complex, though you might be able to evade forms altogether then.

[0] Actually, depending on your requirements, it seems you could create an `AgentTag` instance for each `Tag` as soon as new `Agent` is saved (with empty `AgentTag.experience`, which you’d have to make nullable), but that’s not really important.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. There's 215 tags (we show/hide different sections of them by Javascript), so instantiating that many forms on both the GET and the POST feels like a lot of server work. I'm tempted just to add the current state of the data structure to the context, manually render the checkboxes, then update the model from the POST response, bypassing Django forms entirely. Let me know if you feel this is a bad idea.

Comment: While I don’t think instantiating 215 forms is necessarily a big hassle (if you avoid making any DB queries in the loop), it definitely makes sense to ditch forms altogether if you only have to show one experience selector for each tag. It’d also make that selector somewhat easier to customize—no need to dive into form widgets and stuff.